# How do I copy an encrypted DVD in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: encryption, dvd, copy

I have tried several programs such as Brassero to copy an encrypted DVD but without success. I tried to install libdvdcss but was unable to do it (key not found?).

What version of libdvdcss do I need for Ubuntu 16.04 and how do I install it? Or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Ask the system:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache search libdvdcss
brasero - CD/DVD burning application for GNOME
gxine - the xine video player, GTK+/Gnome user interface
libdvdread4 - library for reading DVDs
python3-dvdvideo - Video DVD reader library
kubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used media codecs and fonts for Kubuntu
libdvd-pkg - DVD-Video playing library - installer
lubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used media codecs and fonts for Lubuntu
ubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used media codecs and fonts for Ubuntu
xubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used media codecs and fonts for Xubuntu
libdvdcss2 - library for accessing encrypted DVDs
libdvdcss-dev - library for accessing encrypted DVDs - development files
```

You need to `sudo apt install` one or more of these packages.

Ignoring your "unable to do it (key not found?)" message due to lack of specific information.

Comment: It turns out most of these were already installed except python3 which is now installed. Still no joy. I tried handbrake, brassero, vlc, k3b and they all stall at 3% and hang. The dvd is encrypted. Other dvds work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to be the answer that you want as your question doesn't indicate exactly what you are trying to do, however, you can obtain an exact copy of any block device by utilizing the method outlined [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694) Since you are creating an image of the device contents without regard to what those contents are, the encryption will be duplicated along with everything else. During the process of attempting to image the disk you may discover that the problem isn't the encryption, but scratches or smudges or a device problem instead. This will be made clearer by the I/O errors that dd will provide in the attempt.