# DVD cannot be read in Xubuntu Linux 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, video, vlc, dvd, gstreamer

There is an issue with reading DVDs in Xubuntu. I am running Xubuntu Linux 22.04 on a 2010 MacBook Pro. I am trying to play a regular DVD with encrypted copyright protection (not Blu Ray). Whenever I try to read DVDs on Parole Media Player, an error message appears that states "Gstreamer backend error: Could not open CD device for reading". I have researched solutions, and I've installed Ubuntu Restricted drivers and libdvdcss, however to no avail. VLC doesn't seem to do any better as well. Is there a different approach I can take to solve this issue? I've tried using SMPlayer, VLC, and Kaffine and I'm at a roadblock trying to solve this issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to install libdvd-pkg ?

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
```

After that you'll need to configure :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

source :

> https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/video-dvd-restricted.html.en

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I ran those commands, the terminal said I already had that package installed, and it has already been configured.

Comment: I'm sorry. Just now I found another help page : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs : have you tried these hints ? This thread also seems interesting : https://askubuntu.com/a/1102082/1024363 ( `apt-cache search libdvdcss` or `sudo apt search libdvdcss` to identify some missing packages ?)

Comment: Sadly, those methods haven't worked either.